# Using wireshark to only capture the traffic between my computer and a specific host

Tags: networking, java, wireshark

I'm a .NET developer who's used to using fiddler.  I'm trying just see the traffic from a web service running on my local machine and a specific web service.  When I hit this web service from an ASP.NET website running in Visual Studio I can see the traffic in fiddler.

I'm trying to hit the same web service from a Java application and for some reason the traffic doesn't show up in fiddler, event thought I have filters turned off and I have exempt all set in WinConfig.

I figured that my Java application and my web service would probably show up in Wireshark so I decided to give that a try.  When I run Wireshark it seems like it's showing me all kinds of traffic.  I tried adding a capture filter

```
http.host contains "mywebservicefullyqualifiedhostname"
```

But I keep seeing traffic going to many different ip addresses.  I used nslookup to check into some of these ip addresses and none of them are my web service.

I removed the https.host contains filter and and added these two capture filters:

```
src host 1.2.3.4
host 4.3.2.1
```

Where src 1.2.3.4 is my ip address and 4.3.2.1 is the ip address I'm connecting to, but it's still showing bunches of other ip addresses when I start capturing traffic in Wireshark.

Is there anyway to add a host name to the columns in Wireshark?  Are the capture filters in Wireshark a list of things to exclude?  Looking at the default capture filters in Wireshark it doesn't appear so e.g.

```
not port 80 and not port 25 and host www.wireshark.org
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your capture filter should look something like this (make sure to select the appropriate interface). Does it?

[image: capture]

Comment: That seemed to work.  I was entering my capture filters via Capture -> Capture Filters and then hitting the plus button and entering a name and filter.  Any idea why that doesn't work?

Comment: In my experience, Wireshark filters are really fickle from a formatting perspective. I sometimes have to slam my head against them for some time until I get them to work as expected. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯